# Squid Cannot allocate memory

Tags: linux, docker, proxy, fork, squid

I was trying to build squid container which work as proxy for list of users and use different configuration such as "login using custom python script" ssl bump to stop https urls and some ACL rules

but i get that most of time squid is very slow and take much time to be up and ready and slow to use

when i read the cache.log file i get always

> ipcCreate: fork: (12) Cannot allocate memory

I tried also to run docker container using "--memory-swap -1" flag and still same

**df -h in the docker container :**

> Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
>
> none             30G   16G   14G  54% /
>
> tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /dev
>
> tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
>
> /dev/xvda1       30G   16G   14G  54% /etc/hosts
>
> shm              64M  2.1M   62M   4% /dev/shm
>
> tmpfs           496M     0  496M   0% /sys/firmware

Comment: How much memory are you having? Are you running this under a VM?

Comment: No , using amazon ec2 with docker

Comment: This is "df -h" result in the container :  /dev/xvda1       30G   16G   14G  54% /etc/hosts

Comment: Please update these things in question and not in commnets

Comment: question edited!